# Avoid Spring application log out on browser close

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, tomcat7

I have a weird problem and not able to fix it.

**The Problem :**

I login to my Spring web application which has long session timeout, whenever I quit the browser and then reopen it, access my web-app and I see login page every time.

It works fine as long as browser is not closed. I thought that there is some problem with the chrome settings, but it's not. Also it happens with all the browsers.

**My `web.xml`:**

```xml
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10000</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
            <name>myapp</name>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
        </cookie-config>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>
```

**My Spring Security configuration:**

```xml
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login/forgot" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login/resetpassword" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/home/admin/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_admin', 'ROLE_manager')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_admin', 'ROLE_manager','ROLE_user')" />
        <security:form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            login-processing-url="/login" 
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureFilter" 
            authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"  
            username-parameter="email" 
            password-parameter="password" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <security:csrf/>

    </security:http>
```

Is there any problem with my `web.xml` or Spring Security?

Comment: Check the javax.http.servlet.cookie class max age attribute, the default value is -1 which is delete the cookie if the browser is shutdown.

Comment: @notionquest yeah problemo solved

Comment: Added the answer. Please accept if it was useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please set the max age attribute of the cookie.

> By default, -1 is returned, which indicates that the cookie will
>   persist until browser shutdown.

[Http Servlet Cookie Max Age](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setMaxAge-int-)